# Develop for ACR122U Reader with .NET on Mac

Tags: .net, macos, nfc, pcsc, acr122

I have a KKMoon ACR122U-A9 reader and have downloaded the latest required drivers for it. I'm using Sierra 10.12.2 and can connect to the reader using the **pcsctest** terminal command. However after hours of research, I still can't find a way of reading/writing data to cards using the .NET framework on Mac. Almost all examples I found were Windows based. I have tried the **pcsc-sharp** Nuget package, with some success, but it only fully supports Windows and Unix.

Am I going to have to run Windows in order to create a .NET program to communicate with the reader? Or is there a Mac library that can help me?

Comment: .NET is a requirement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think using .NET framework on OS X is a good idea. If .NET is not a requirement, you can use Java.

You can find [grundig nfctools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) library to develop NFC applications with Java support.

You can find also [grundig nfctools-examples](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools-examples) that are developed using an ACR122U that should facilitate your work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm afraid .NET is a requirement and unfortunately the more I research, the more I think that I'll have to use Windows to develop for the card reader

Comment: If you need to use .NET I suggest you to stop searching. NFC is a not a simply thing, so combining NFC difficulty with adapting .NET libs to OS X could be very complex

Comment: Thats solid advice. I'll look into other options